# How do I stop KWallet from asking my password to let the system connect to WiFi?

Tags: security, wifi, kwallet

I've just switched to KDE and although I feel interested in exploring the opportunity to use KWallet for all kinds of cryptographic key/certificate files and some browser passwords perhaps if it can do that (I don't know yet), I absolutely don't want to enter my password every time I want to connect to WiFi. In fact I have to enter my password twice at the boot time now - to log-in and to get WiFi connected right after that and I find this is very annoying.

Is it possible to disable KWallet WiFi passwords management and let the network selection applet (or whatever it is) remember it itself or to configure KWallet to just stop requiring explicit authorization for things this simple?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that KDEWallet will manage all encrypted passwords unless disabled (bad idea in my opinion), so in order to avoid having to put the password for wifi, you will have to avoid encryption on wifi networks.

All you have to do is go to **"Networks"**(Wifi Icon) then **"Configure Network Connections"** (Looks like sliders) then choose on the left panel the wifi you want to configure then on the right side of the menu choose the TAB **"Wifi security"** finally you will see below "Store password for this user only (encrypted)" change it to **"store password for all users (not encrypted)"**

You just have to remember this when adding more networks.

Answer (score 6):

On KDE 5, in the System Settings app **KDE Wallet**, enable the option **Different wallet for local passwords**.

Then: **create a new wallet** for this option, **select Blowfish** encryption for it, and **click OK to set a BLANK password**.

WiFi passwords now get chucked into this wallet and there's no password prompt to "open" it whenever the system needs access to it.

(Note: KWallet is both annoying as well as insecure, as it allows *any app* to request full access to ***all** passwords stored in a wallet* once that wallet is open...)

Answer (score 0):

There will by only lack of encryption on password file.

If you encrypt whole your system, then there is no problem :)